# Rails bundle install Could not find turbo-rails-7.1.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-7

On a brand new digitalocean droplet running Ubuntu 20.10 with a brand new pretty near empty rails 7 alpha 2 app running `bundle install` results in the following both when running cap production deploy on my local machine and when running from the command shell on the droplet

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Could not find turbo-rails-7.1.1 in any of the sources
```

I have no issues locally with this so this has to be an environment issue on the production server or some configuration option I've missed somehere.
I am using latest stable rvm which is correctly configured,

```
rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-3.0.0 (found in /home/comtechmaster/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0)
   (default)
   global
=> master_cms
```

I used a capistrano script to deploy the app and latest stable version node was installed using nvm.
Bundler is the same version on both environments and turbo-rails-7.1.1 does not appear anywhere in my gemfile.lock

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran into this also. Not sure why, but they yanked the 7.x versions and regressed to 0.8.x:

https://rubygems.org/gems/turbo-rails/versions/7.1.1

Just add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 0.8'
```

And then run and run `./bin/bundle update turbo-rails` and you should be good.

Comment: Release says the other versions were: [made in error](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/releases/tag/v0.8.2)

Comment: `~> 0.9` is now out as of Nov 24.

Comment: now upgrade it by adding `gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 0.9.1'` in your gemfile

Comment: Currently it would be `gem 'turbo-rails', '~> 1.0'` . Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case removing Gemfile.lock and running install again worked.

Comment: I'm pleased that worked for you, I am sure that it will help others, my accepted answer was the only solution that worked for me though

Comment: pretty sure removing Gemfile.lock will not correct the yanked version from 7.x to 0.x